# miller-rabin test don't work for 252097800623

Tags: c++, algorithm, number-theory

I'm trying to write miller-rabin test. I found few codes such as:

https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-miller-rabin-primality-test/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-3-miller-rabin/

Of course all this codes works for 252097800623 ( which is prime number ), but this is becaouse they are parsing it to int. When I changed all ints to long long in this codes they are now returning NO. I also wrote my own code based on another article and it worked when I was testing it with small numbers like 11, 101, 17 and even 1000000007, but chrashed on greater numbers like 252097800623. I want to write program that works for all integers from 1 to 10^18

EDIT

here is modified code form 1st link:

```
/* 

 * C++ Program to Implement Milong longer Rabin Primality Test

 */

#include <iostream>

#include <cstring>

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;



/* 

 * calculates (a * b) % c taking long longo account that a * b might overflow 

 */

long long mulmod(long long a, long long b, long long mod)

{

    long long x = 0,y = a % mod;

    while (b > 0)

    {

        if (b % 2 == 1)

        {    

            x = (x + y) % mod;

        }

        y = (y * 2) % mod;

        b /= 2;

    }

    return x % mod;

}

/* 

 * modular exponentiation

 */

long long modulo(long long base, long long exponent, long long mod)

{

    long long x = 1;

    long long y = base;

    while (exponent > 0)

    {

        if (exponent % 2 == 1)

            x = (x * y) % mod;

        y = (y * y) % mod;

        exponent = exponent / 2;

    }

    return x % mod;

}



/*

 * Milong longer-Rabin primality test, iteration signifies the accuracy

 */

bool Miller(long long p,long long iteration)

{

    if (p < 2)

    {

        return false;

    }

    if (p != 2 && p % 2==0)

    {

        return false;

    }

    long long s = p - 1;

    while (s % 2 == 0)

    {

        s /= 2;

    }

    for (long long i = 0; i < iteration; i++)

    {

        long long a = rand() % (p - 1) + 1, temp = s;

        long long mod = modulo(a, temp, p);

        while (temp != p - 1 && mod != 1 && mod != p - 1)

        {

            mod = mulmod(mod, mod, p);

            temp *= 2;

        }

        if (mod != p - 1 && temp % 2 == 0)

        {

            return false;

        }

    }

    return true;

}

//Main

int main()

{

    long long iteration = 5;

    long long num;

    cout<<"Enter long longeger to test primality: ";

    cin>>num;

    if (Miller(num, iteration))

        cout<<num<<" is prime"<<endl;

    else

        cout<<num<<" is not prime"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In the first link, everything relevant is already `long long`.

Comment: when i changed all to long long it doesn't

Comment: Instead of linking to a bunch of different sites posting some code in an article/blog entry with a rough description of your modification, please edit your question and include the exact version of the code that you are running and that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the first link, which you replicated in your question, replacing the (bad) macro `ll` with `long long` (although this produces exactly the same preprocessed code) and all `int` with `long long`, is already broken for large values, see [compiler explorer here](https://godbolt.org/z/KI41_2). I forced the compiler to evaluate the `Miller` function for `252097800623` at compile time, replacing the call to `rand()` with one random number `123456`.

As you can see the compiler is telling me that it cannot do so, because there are integer overflows in the program. In particular:

```
<source>:133:17: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
  static_assert(Miller(num, iteration));
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:62:12: note: value 232307310937188460801 is outside the range of representable values of type 'long long'
    y = (y * y) % mod;
           ^
<source>:104:14: note: in call to 'modulo(123457, 63024450155, 252097800623)'
    ll mod = modulo(a, temp, p);
             ^
<source>:133:17: note: in call to 'Miller(252097800623, 5)'
  static_assert(Miller(num, iteration));
```

As you can see `long long` is simply too small to handle inputs that large to this algorithm.